# How to login with another user when using Google for login?

Tags: php, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

I am using Google login to authenticate user before they login to my website.

Here is what I am doing.

1. User comes to my website
2. Click on login button
3. Login with Google account
4. if user pass google authentication, session is set
5. when user click on logout, session is destroyed

Basic stuff!

Problem I am facing, happens when two users using same device tries to use the website.

- UserA logs in to the website using his Google account.
- UserA do his stuff and log out.
- UserB then comes and try to login to website. Because userA is already logged into Google, Google authentication process does not ask userB for his credentials and carry on logging in with UserA account.

My question is how can I make user log out from Google when user log out from my website.

Comment: "__UserA do his stuff and log out.__" ...  "__Because userA is already logged__"  shouldn't `userA` be already logged out by now ?

Comment: User A is logged out from my website not from Google. When UserB tries to login to my website, he is not asked for credentials by Google Authentication Process because UserA is still logged into Google. Google thinks it is still UserA and login into my website as userA.

Comment: "__when user click on logout, session is destroyed ... Basic stuff!__" It's not so basic after all because a new user from the same device can login automatically, I would suggest you read __carefully__ the documentation of the class, plugin or script you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setPrompt to 'select_account'**. Google will ask to select account each time authentication request is made .

I do not think your users are happy with being logged out after logging out your page... They can change their account within the Google page.

This is the url for logging out:

```
accounts.google.com/logout
```

You can pass a redirect parameter there:

```
accounts.google.com/logout?continue=http://www.google.com/
```

But this parameter just work with links to Google services. There is no way to link your own page (not even with Google search redirect links). I think there is a very good reason for this. You should not log out your users from another foreign service for any reason.

Comment: "__I do not think your users are happy with being logged out after logging out your page__" this doesn't happen, they only logout from the OP website.

Comment: how do you suggest I tackle this problem.

Comment: @PedroLobito: Question was "My question is how can I make user log out from Google when user log out from my website."

Comment: @SandeepSingh: I think there is no solution for logging out the users from Google. Is there no option within Googles OAuth API for user switching on Googles page?

Comment: Two possibilities: Set `approval_prompt` to `force`, then the user can change the identity. Or set `login_hint` to the users googlemail address if you know with which he want to login before.

Comment: The author edited my post and inserted the first sentence. I think this is the best solution for this, but I have not found it in the docu yesterday. :D